# How to pass arguments while generating RSA key pair in java?

Tags: java, rsa, key-pair

I am trying to generate a RSA key pair in java using the following snippet.

`KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"); keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);`

How do I pass arguments like alias name, organizational unit, locality, validity etc.,

When we try to generate using keytool we can pass them directly in the command. How do we do it while using the KeyPairGenerator class.

Answer (score 0):

A key pair ([java.security.KeyPair](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyPair.html)) is literally just a public key and corresponding private key. The reason you can't give KeyPairGenerator any other arguments is that there's nothing it could do with them.

The reason that `keytool` *does* take other arguments is that it manages a key *store*, which holds more than just a key pair; it can potentially hold a bunch of different key pairs and certificates, plus metadata about them.

So I think that the classes you're looking for are [java.security.Keystore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) and [java.security.cert.CertificateFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) (and related classes).